# Get status of progress of simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to know the progress of simulink. `SimulationStatus` only gives a very basic information:

```
get_param(gcs,'SimulationStatus')
```

I need something like this:

```
set_param(gcs, 'SimulationCommand', 'start');
pause(200)
if ??progress?? < 10 % percent
    set_param(gcs, 'SimulationCommand', 'stop');
    error('Progress so slow')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of

```
timeNow = get_param(gcs,'SimulationTime');
```

and

```
timeEnd = get_param(gcs,'StopTime');
```

to determine how far into the simulation you are.

You might also want to investigate using a [Timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) instead of `pause(200)` so that your command line isn't blocked.